# Косящетый и муравленый - это какой?

Tags: лексика

> Полъ въ церкви и трапезѣ былъ деревяный косящетый, а печи — въ алтарѣ
>   и трапезѣ — муравленыя...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Полъ въ церкви и трапезѣ былъ деревяный **косящетый**...

[***"Более 1400 лет составляет история изготовления художественного паркета..."***](http://www.centrparketa.ru/?p=13)

> В социально значимых зданиях древней Руси были деревянные полы, из
>   ровных керамических плиток, а также мозаичные. Но в России первенство
>   получил деревянный пол из досок, деревянные кирпичи и художественный
>   паркет. Укладка в начале шестнадцатого века в России имела следующую
>   технологию - полы стали стелить дубовыми клепками и по-особому
>   укладывая их рисунком, который получил название **«елочка»**, сам же пол
>   получил название **«косящатый»**.

Answer (score 2):

Косящетый – (по Далю) косой, наклонный, а "муравленные" – покрытые глазурью, изразцами.

Comment: С печами понятно, но - косой или наклонный пол?!

Comment: По Далю "косой пол" – лежащий не по уровню, одним краем,концом ниже.